# How do I flip the values of my array?

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [501] => 115
    [500] => 294
    [499] => 155
```

The last value, 155 should match with key 501. Essentially, I need to flip the values while preserving the key order. I've already looked and the only thing I can find is `array_reverse` which won't help. Do I need to break this array apart and do it myself or is there a native PHP function that will do it?

---

Here is what I get with I use `array_reverse($myOldArray)`

```
Array
(
    [0] => 115
    [1] => 294
    [2] => 155
```

I need array key 501 to match 155.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_reverse()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) *twice*:

> Takes an input array and returns a new array with the order of the elements reversed.

```
$new_array = array_reverse(array_reverse($array), true);
```

The first call reverses your values. The second one changes the keys and values so they are in the order you want.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm using that now and that is what is giving me the DESC keys. What I need now is to order the keys in reverse.

Comment: Oops. I have the second param set to true. Let me remove that and see if that helps.

Comment: @NaN: Seems like you have to call `array_reverse` twice, to put  the keys back in the original order.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't giving me what I need either. I'll edit my post with the results.

Comment: I see your edit, John. I'll try that now. Thanks again.

Comment: That works, John. Thanks. Can you explain what this is doing? I'm not completely following the logic here.

Comment: Basically the first reverse only affects the values. It puts them in the order you want. But now your keys and values are in the opposite order you want. So the second call to array_reverse changes the order of the keys *and* values so they are in the order you want.

Comment: Take a look at the array_reverse documentation.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php.  The first time around, he's using `true` for the `$preserve_keys` parameter in the `array_reverse()` function to preserve the key order.  The second time around he's just switching the order of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, guys. I'll have a look at the docs. Axel, you're right, what you describe is what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$l = sizeof($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < (int) ($l/2); $i++) {
    $temp = $arr[i];
    $arr[$i] = $arr[$l-$i];
    $arr[$l-$i] = $arr[$i];
}
```